# Intel 855GME Driver Not Enabled

Tags: unity, graphics, intel

I have a Toshiba-r15s822 Tablet PC and I just made the switch to Linux, Ubuntu was the build of choice, thing is I tried it before and everything worked fine (about 2 years ago, I think stuff are different now).

Almost everything is working well but the Intel display driver isn't enabled, I tried updating the intel drivers from the Intel repos, and modding the `xorg.conf` file, but I can't get it to work, any ideas?

Another question: it's a little bit faster after enabling Unity2d, but is Ubuntu 10.4 faster than this?  Or slower?  And will downgrading give me a speedboost, because this is much slower than my earlier Windows XP build :(

Also I got my eyes on the 12.04 version, should I downgrade or upgrade?

P.S - I scoured around for solutions to this, on the web and on askubuntu.com, I've tried most of the solutions but no avail, hope you can help me

Specs go here

- 1.6ghz centrino processor
- 1.5GB or ram
- Intel 855GME with 64mbs of RAM

Comment: You shall not run Unity in any form with those specs, Install Lubuntu.

Comment: OpenGl and thus 3D acceleration has been enabled for the chipset since ver. 2.6 , you can check more here in this ubuntuforums thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-40865.html

Comment: The thing here is that the chipset lacks some support that Unity needs.

Comment: Also take a look at this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1849604

Comment: whoops sorry didn't refresh quick enough *reading now*

Comment: Now having said that, Lubuntu will run smoother as it is less taxing than Ubuntu.

Comment: So bottom line is, it is supported (alas, will run video/google earth/browser games as needed) but i won't have the eye-candy of unity, similar to aero on windows 7?

also i hope i don't lose my wacom tablet functions in lubuntu, any compromises? ;O having tasted unity it's so hard to roll back haha, but thanks for your time!

Comment: Indeed, it's a pretty old chipset and it does what it can in these modern times of flashing UIs, to have some Compositing you can install `xcompmgr`in Lubuntu, set it to autostart, and you'll have basic Compositing needed for Transparecy in most docks and the LXDE panel.

Comment: You can too customize the LXDE panel to have the Indicators the Unity top panel has and install AWN and customize it to look like the Unity launcher.

Comment: @URiHerrera Yeah, it's my beloved ol' tablet PC, Can't replace it currently because tablet PCs are so overpriced, maybe in a year when i graduate, One last question: any recommendations for the version is should install? the 12.04 looks tasty but i think i'll go for 11.4, what do you think? :)

Comment: 12.04 is buggy as hell at least in my case, can't say it will be the same in the Tablet that you have, 11.10 is what is the current release so use that one.

Comment: I'll go by that, Thank you so much for your time ^w^ god bless~<3

Answer (score 3):

OpenGl and thus 3D acceleration has been enabled for the chipset since ver. 2.6 , you can check more here in these ubuntuforums threads:

- [855GME/915 Drivers from Intel](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-40865.html)
- [Intel 855GME 3D acceleration](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1849604)

The thing here is that the chipset lacks some support that Unity needs.

If Ubuntu is too heavy for your device Install Lubuntu.

To have some Compositing you can install `xcompmgr` in Lubuntu, set it to autostart, and you'll have basic Compositing needed for Transparecy in most docks and the LXDE panel.

You can too customize the LXDE panel to have the Indicators like in the Unity top panel and install AWN and customize it to look like the Unity launcher.